# Android Google Play Leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have developed an android game.I used Google Play Leaderboard in my game.
My problem is the leaderboard scores are'nt shown in app. The leaderboard interface comes up but says "No leaderboards for this game".User scores do not appear.

this is saving codes of score

```
PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult> result = Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getApiClient(),getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard), LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC);
                        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult loadPlayerScoreResult) {
                                if(loadPlayerScoreResult != null && loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore() != null) {
                                    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard), loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore() + value);}
                                else {
                               Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard), value); }
                            }});
```

Any ideas?What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've set up your leaderboard properly on Google Play Console. There you will [Create your Leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard) first and then you will [Add Leaderboard to your game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards).